# Certificação de Processo de Qualidade: como obter?

Tags: engenharia-de-software

Tenho um sistema e quero certificá-lo. Minha ideia é o ISO 9001.

O que é preciso fazer? Quais são os requisitos para se obter esta certificação?

Devo procurar uma empresa para obter a certificação ou há outros meios de certificar a aplicação, como por exemplo pagar apenas pela homologação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A norma ISO 9001](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/management-standards/iso_9000.htm) normalmente é usada para a gestão de qualidade em empresas e organizações, mas pode ser perfeitamente usada para a gestão de qualidade do desenvolvimento de um sistema, em teoria.

Para que seja satisfeita a implementação da norma, a parte interessada [deve se atentar a uma série de requisitos](http://www.fasi.edu.br/files/biblioteca/NBR_iso9001.pdf), como a produção de documentação sobre os processos adotados e as respectivas premissas de qualidade usadas nesse controle de qualidade, como o uso de um software só para isso, por exemplo.

Não é comum haver a aplicação da norma no desenvolvimento do software porque a norma não traz agilidade ao desenvolvimento, além de encarecer todo o processo. O que é mais comum é termos disponíveis no mercado sistemas que façam este controle de qualidade e consequente aplicação correta da norma.

Implementação e certificação pela norma ISO são duas etapas em separado, normalmente feitas por empresas de consultoria, que visitam o negócio com a função de encontrar e mitigar problemas processuais. No seu contexto, duas coisas podem ser homologadas:

- O processo de desenvolvimento do seu software;
- O seu software, que pode ter sido feito para atender à gestão da qualidade numa empresa e ao consequente cumprimento da norma.